# Mongodb got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends centos 7.5

Tags: mongodb, centos7, mongodb4.0

I am getting Mongodb 4.0.4 crash got signal 15 (Terminated) in Centos 7.5 after server restart. I have found mongodb log from log file. please suggest me what should I need to do for start this service.

`2019-02-28T17:00:52.978+0530 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] got signal 15 (Terminated), will terminate after current cmd ends
2019-02-28T17:00:52.978+0530 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2019-02-28T17:00:52.978+0530 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2019-02-28T17:00:52.978+0530 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] now exiting
2019-02-28T17:00:52.978+0530 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] shutting down with code:0`

Please help me I am stuck in my live project. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/867444/mongodb-why-the-mongod-service-is-shutdown

Comment: As I have fixed this issue when your total collection of Database increase more than 64000 than mongodb react something diffrent way.It is mongodb limitation for 64000 collection size than it can any time can stop the mongod service,so as per my suggestion you have to make sure about your collection size